# how to convert a table data into json object

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have Table in Snowflake which has names

```
select * from names 

f_name  l_name
==============
John    Flex
Jerry   Paul
Ravi    kumar
```

Expected Output:

```
{
"names" :[
"John",
"Flex",
"Jerry",
"Paul",
"Ravi"]
}
```

Comment: docs ? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-rest-apis.html#endpoint-loadhistoryscan

Comment: Assuming you are wanting a JSON array of names, any normally an arrays order does not imply relationship, it seems slightly strange to put both first names and last names into the same array.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I think there are two steps:

1. Using ARRAY_AGG to create an array of all names: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_agg.html
2. Using OBJECT_CONSTRUCT to create your json-object with key=names and values= your final array, i.e. result of array_agg(): https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_construct.html

Answer (score 0):

I feels wrong to mix first names and last names together, but one way with zero respect for order is

```
with data as (
 select * from values 
    ('John', 'Flex'),
    ('Jerry', 'Paul'),
    ('Ravi', 'kumar')
    v(f_name,l_name)
)
select object_construct('name', array_cat(array_agg(f_name), array_agg(l_name)))
from data;
```

which gives:

```
{ "name": [ "John", "Jerry", "Ravi", "Flex", "Paul", "kumar" ]}
```

it feels like it would make more sense to have structured JSON data via:

```
with data as (
    select * from values 
    ('John', 'Flex'),
    ('Jerry', 'Paul'),
    ('Ravi', 'kumar')
    v(f_name,l_name)
)
select object_construct('name', array_agg(object_construct('first_name',f_name,'last_name',l_name)))
from data
```

which gives:

```
{ "name": [ { "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Flex" }, { "first_name": "Jerry", "last_name": "Paul" }, { "first_name": "Ravi", "last_name": "kumar" } ] }
```